# Can you access a object's attributes with only its variable address?

Tags: python, arrays, attributes

How can I iterate through linked arrays more effectively?

```
global matrix

#initalize matrix as a 2d array 50 by 50

class cell:
    def __init___(self, x, y):
        self.i = x
        self.j = y
        self.array = []

#each matrix index has a cell object
for i in range(0, 50):
    for j in range(0, 50):
        matrix[i][j] = cell(i, j)

#each cell has an array of other cells
matrix[0][0].array = [matrix[0][1], matrix[1][0], matrix[1][1]]



#prints out a cell from an array of another
print("Example 1: ", matrix[0][0].array[0])

>>> Example 1: <__main__.cell object at 0x000001F4426D5F40>



#to link cells the 'dot' operator is used repeatedly
matrix[0][0].array[0].array = [matrix[0][0], matrix[2][1], matrix[1][2]]



#to access other cells down the chain the 'dot' operator is repeatedly
print("Example 2: ", matrix[0][0].array[0].array[0])

>>> Example 2: <__main__.cell object at 0x000001F4428EB0A0>
```

The problem is finding how to go through arrays without using the 'dot' operator repeatedly

Comment: What do you mean "it's variables location"? You are going to have to provide a [mcve] and a clear problem statement

Comment: The location of what object?

Comment: @matineau In the last line of my question, there is a memory location address, ''0x000001FFF7745BE0". I was wondering if there was a way to access this object and its attributes with just using this memory address because I wanted to view and change some of the attributes of the object

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I apologize, is it more clear now?

Comment: @AlonsoOrtiz *that is the object*. That's the standard printed representation of an object inherited from `object.__repr__`.  So if you want to access the object, just use `myobject = matrix[0][0].array[0].array[0]` then work with `myobject`

Comment: Fundamentally, python is a high level language. There are hacks you can do to access and object using the id of the PyObject header, which is *an implementation detail* about CPython's `id` function. It isn't meant to be used as an address, it is simply meant to be used as a unique ID. Instead, concentrate on *what useful data structures* your program will utilize.

Comment: I understand that was very helpful. When you put it that way it is pretty simple. I appreciate it @juanpa.arrivillaga